# I want to know the compatibility between CPU and motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Im planning on building a PC and was wondering if ryzen 7 2700x cpu was compatible with lga2011-3 series CPU housing

Comment: You cannot fit an AMD CPU in an Intel socket.

Comment: Check the motherboard specifications, you will find, the AMD processor isn’t listed as being compatible